# Run python script automatically every week (windows)

Tags: python, windows

I wrote a little python Script that fetches data from some website using hard coded credentials ( i know its bad but not part of this question).

The website has new data every day and im gathering data from a whole week and parse it into a single .pdf.

I've already adjusted the script to always generate a pdf off last week by default. (no params needed)

Im kinda lazy and don't want to run the script every week by hand.

So is it possible to run the script at certain times, for example every monday at 10am?

Comment: Windows has the task scheduler for that.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Soya In case you like [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51026970/7803436) and it helped you then it would be polite if you'd mark it as answered. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just utilize [Windows' task scheduler](http://tips4pc.com/Computer_tips_and_tricks/how_to_open_task_scheduler_and_set_tasks.htm). There you can create new tasks to your delight and let it run commands to whatever times or intervalls you want. The task schedulers' GUI should be self-explanatory, but to be concrete on your example:

1. Configure the **run time** (weekly, monday, 10am) under **triggers**
2. Add a new **action** and give it your Python interpreter as the **command** and your script to be run as the **argument**
3. Configure the rest according to your needs